# Fastest way to extract only certain fields from comma separated string in Python

Tags: python, performance, csv, split

Say I have a string containing data from a DB or spreadsheet in comma separated format.

For example:

```
data = "hello,how,are,you,232.3354,good morning"
```

Assume that there are maybe 200 fields in these "records".

I am interested in looking at just certain fields of this record. What is the fastest way in Python to get at them?

The most simple way would be something like:

```
fields = data.split(",")
result = [fields[4], fields[12], fields[123]]
```

Is there a faster way to do this, making use of the fact that:

1. You only need to allocate a list with 3 elements and 3 string objects for the result.
2. You can stop scanning the data string once you reach field 123.

I have tried to write some code using repeated calls to find to skip passed commas but if the last field is too far down the string this becomes slower than the basic split solution.

I am processing several million records so any speedup would be welcome.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to beat the native `str.split()` with a Python solution.

Comment: I have no idea if it's faster or not, but you can avoid splitting the entire string with `data.split(",", 124)`.

Comment: are you sure it is a bottleneck in your application? How much faster do you need it to be to shift the bottleneck somewhere else in your app?

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to do too much better than loading everything into memory and then dropping the parts that you need. My recommendation is compression and a better library.

As it happens I have a couple reasonably sized csv's lying around (this one is 500k lines).

```
> import gzip
> import pandas as pd
> %timeit pd.read_csv(gzip.open('file.csv.gz'))
1 loops, best of 3: 545 ms per loop
```

Dropping the columns is also pretty fast, I'm not sure what the major cost is.

```
> %timeit csv[['col1', 'col2']]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If `result` can be a `tuple` instead of a list, you might gain a bit of a speedup (if you're doing multiple calls) using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
indexer = itemgetter(4,12,123)
result = indexer(data.split(','))
```

You'd need to `timeit` to actually see if you get a speedup or not though.